# Is giving lightsabers to young children safe?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Yoda is teaching a group of younglings in AotC:

[image: younglings with chainsaws]

Isn't that equivalent to handing them chainsaws without protection?

Comment: Besides the fact that Yoda can stop them from hurting each other as long as he is around. He can use the force to stop their movement

Comment: What the Jedi don't tell you when they take your child is that that child has a 99% chance of dying during training. You'll never see them again anyway, so you're none the wiser.

Answer (score 5):

According to AotC novellization, younglings were trained with 'light' versions of the real lightsaber, with limited energy field that could produce no real harm.

Likewise, in ANH, we see Luke Skywalker training in combat against a training droid, that does not cause damage, only irritates.

Comment: Book quote pending...

Comment: In star wars the old Republic, the kids train with wooden sticks as well. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R51LMIAJtsc) shows it at 1:14 and at 6:38

Comment: You might say it's a.... *lite-saber*